# What does $$ after a file's extension represent in Perl?

Tags: perl

I tried to research on the `$$`, but only could find on a different example like $$tmp 
where it says it's a symbolic references.

In my code it uses `my $sftp_batch = "/tmp/poll.$$";` —
it's used for a file extension. 
What does it represent — what does it mean?

Comment: To find out about built-in variables, you can run `perldoc perlvar`. This is much easier than searching for "perl double dollar sign" or "perl dollar dollar" in Google :)

Comment: You could always try `print "/tmp/poll.$$"` in Perl just to see what you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$
>
> The process number of the Perl running this script.

See: [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Every time you run your script, it will get a `pid` or `process number` in the underlying operating system. If your pid is `1234`, the tempfile will be called `/tmp/poll.1234`, etc.

The point is to create a unique file name, one that no other process on the machine will create while this process is running.